# Change all values in dataframe to NA or 0

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

How do I change all values in a dataset to NA or 0, while preserving all column names and ideally, preserving an identical data structure.

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: I tried some is.na conditional formatting but the answer here works better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can just do assignment while using `[]` to preserve the attributes

```
df1[] <- 0
```

Or for `NA`

```
df1[] <- NA
```

-testing

```
> df1 <- head(iris, 3)
> df1[] <- 0
> df1
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1            0           0            0           0       0
2            0           0            0           0       0
3            0           0            0           0       0
```